# Shift color of string between two | star sign

Tags: php, if-statement, colors, between, sign

If possible

> Blockquote

**tell me** *how I can word color change if between two star sign*?
thanks alot

Comment: you only need to tag php + the only useful part from the question is **How can I change the color of words if they are between two star signs?**. So what did you try ?

Comment: Text on its own doesn't have colour, it's just text. Are you creating HTML? Do you know what the HTML you want to create looks like? Can you give an example of the input and desired output? Have you done any research, so that you can show us what you've tried already? Click the "edit" link (not "add comment") and add as much detail as you think is relevant to help others help you.